# i can't install the victory-native npm i victory-native

Tags: react-native, npm, charts, expo, victory-native

i can't install the victory-native npm i victory-native please help!
i need to make a group barchart with 2 dataset..
getting this error while installing the victory-native
i can't install the victory-native npm i victory-native please help!
i need to make a group barchart with 2 dataset..
getting this error while installing the victory-native

'npm i victory-native
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...+0m2xEItYuOI3QlKdhofm'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\10k\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-02-01T19_16_28_055Z-debug.log'

Answer (score 1):

The victory-native is required react-native-svg. The react-native-svg didn't support for expo. Please eject your project or use react-native-cli.

> victory-native@^33.0.0 requires react-native-svg@^9.0.0 and react-native@~0.60.0